# How to checked back multiple checkbox from one database field?

Tags: arrays, normalization

I have field hobbies in table, which have; Reading,Sport,Paint

I want to checked back in gridview whichever hobbies's they have.

I insert in table used:

```
 foreach (ListItem item in chkbxHobbies.Items)
 {
     if (item.Selected)
     {
         objBAL.HOBBIES += item + ",";
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

where chkGVHobbies is CheckBoxList control inside gridview.
i hope you already retrive particuler record in DataTable

```
CheckBoxList chkhbs = (CheckBoxList)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("chkGVHobbies");
string hbs = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["hobbies"]);
        string[] str = hbs.Split(',');
        foreach (string item in str)
        {
            foreach (ListItem gvchk in chkhbs.Items)
            {
                if (gvchk.Text==item)
                {
                    gvchk.Selected = true;
                }
            }
```